# How to change background color dynamically in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

In my application I have 10 views, I want **when click** on each item change background color to for example yellow and other view background color is blue.
My views name is, for example : **item1Line**, **item2Line**, **item3Line** and ... **item10Line** . 
I think I can control the views with the loop command and the conditional command.
**I write below codes :**

```
private fun lineColorSelected(item: Int) {
    //Line colors
    for (i in 1..10) {
        if (item == i) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.yellow))
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.blue))
        }
    }
}
```

**Note :** In above code, `view` is sample.
Bu I don't know how can I add my views to list and use this in if condition!

**Update:** Normal way I write below code :

```
    private fun selectedLine(item: Int) {
        binding.apply {
            when (item) {
                1 -> {
                    item1Line.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.meatBrown))
                    item2Line.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.pictonBlue))
                    item3Line.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.pictonBlue))
                }
                2 -> {
                    item1Line.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.pictonBlue))
                    item2Line.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.meatBrown))
                    item3Line.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.pictonBlue))
                }
                3 -> {
                    item1Line.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.pictonBlue))
                    item2Line.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.pictonBlue))
                    item3Line.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.meatBrown))
                }
    }
}
```

But in this way for 10 views is very bad way.
I want use for and if condition for handle above code with best practice.

How can I it?

Comment: Could you please update code of layout and how you are accessing 10 views? Your expectation is the color will be blue and onclick on any item it should be yellow? I couldnt get exactly what is your expectation.

Comment: @GowthamKK , please see my update post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way is

```
// using run so we don't need to go binding.item1Line etc, and the list gets returned
val myItems = binding.run {listOf(
    item1Line, item2Line, item3Line, item4Line, item5Line,
    item6Line, item7Line, item8Line, item9Line, item10Line
)}
```

Then you can do your colour setup with:

```
private fun lineColorSelected(item: Int) {
    myItems.forEachIndexed { i, line ->
        val colour = if (i == item) R.color.meatBrown else R.color.pictonBlue
        line.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), colour)
    }
}
```

When you have a nice list of views like this, you can do things like set up click listeners easily too:

```
myItems.forEachIndexed { i, line ->
    line.setOnClickListener { lineColorSelected(i) }
}
```

**(I'm treating the first item as `0` since I'm using indices, your code uses `1` so be careful of that if you adapt this)**